# Replacing negative values in a dataframe, with zeros

Tags: python, pandas

I have taken some large datasets from csv files, stacked them, and am trying to replace missing and negative values in my final column, with 0's. I believe that I have achieved with the missing values, however, I am unsure with negative values.  Currently my code is as follows (I intend to do further plotting later on):

```
from __future__ import division
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Creation of main and root directory
main_dir = "/Users/Test/Desktop/Data/"
root = main_dir + "Practice/section_1"

# Pathing
paths = [os.path.join(root,v) for v in os.listdir(root) if v.startswith("gas_long_redux_")]


# Importing and Stacking
missing = [' ', 'NA', '.', 'null']

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(v, names = ['ID', 'date_cer', 'kwh']) for v in paths],
    ignore_index = True)

## replace missing values with 0
df = df.fillna(0)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for replacing negative values, or resources for me to look upon?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: ...or `df.clip_lower(0)` might work for you too.

Comment: Thanks.  I did some searching on the clip_lower() portion.  Does this delete values that are negative?

Comment: It returns a copy of the DataFrame with the negative values set to zero.

Comment: Hm, this works for the majority of my values, however I have quite a few values tagged at -999, that are not changing.  Shot in the dark, but is there a reason that these -999 values are not being taken out.

Comment: Actually, fixed that problem.  Thank you for your help.